# Rouge Syntax Highlighting in GitHub Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-extensions, kramdown, rouge

I have been using Rouge and Kramdown to properly format syntax since I've been using Jekyll. I haven't looked in awhile, but recently noticed that the syntax highlighting doesn't appear to be working properly. I noticed that the change broke when GitHub pages started supporting Jekyll 3.9 (was 3.8.5 for the longest time) and the latest version of Rouge. Anyone else find a solution to this? It appears to be broken on many sites that use GitHub Pages and I cannot find a site where it's working.

Here is a URL that does not work: https://www.jasongaylord.com/blog/embed-javascript-in-custom-aspnet-server-controls

Comment: I just rebuild my website and it seems like syntax highlighting is working perfectly. https://svrooij.io/2020/12/31/new-device-for-zigbee2mqtt/ source is at GitHub.com/svrooij/svrooij.GitHub.io

Comment: Also at the page you’re referring to, I see working syntax highlighting

Answer (score 0):

The URL in question that is supposed to show syntax highlighting not working, does in fact appear to have syntax highlighting working correctly.

[Section of your site with syntax highlighting, highlighted by Chrome dev tools. Shows syntax highlighting CSS class provided by Rouge and `data-lang` attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Pv3.png)